# Beat Signal Plot Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm new on Matlab and I'm trying to extract a single heartbeat from a .wav file containing several one. I already managed to display the entire .wav file but I don't find how to detect a heartbeat and especially plot it. This is what I did :

```
[y,fs] = audioread('myfile.wav');
y = y(:,1);
    dt = 1/fs;
    N = length(y);
    t = linspace(0, N/fs, N);
    plot(t,y); xlabel('Seconds'); ylabel('Amplitude');

    threshold = 0.6; 
    if(max(y) > threshold) % Here I tried to dectect the first heartbeat but it doesn't work
        plot(t1,y); % t1 should be the duration of one heartbeat
    end
```

Any ideas on how I could resolve this ? I tried this but I think it has a problem with the Matlab version : http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/projects/beattrack/

Comment: Search for QRS detection algorithms, matlab even comes with an example: http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/examples/real-time-ecg-qrs-detection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built in matlab `findpeaks` function. Here is a [reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) on how to use it.

Comment: Thank you, but now that I have a peak I would like to know how to "zoom" on a single heartbeat, and I don't figure out how to do it with plot.

Comment: Once you find your heartbeat, you can then plot only your selected range of interest.  So, if you find your peak at a coordinate x, such that your max peak it at heartbeat(x), you can do plot(heartbeat(x-range:x+range), where you define range appropriately to "zoom" on your peak